# Xubuntu 14.04 Light Locker Password Not Working

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, password, partitioning

I was trying to install epsxe psx emulator for my desktop. For some reason after I ran the download in the terminal all my partitions got unmounted as i viewed them from my file system and since I restarted my laptop, I cannot unlock from light-locker, my password is being accepted but the screen just reloops to light locker again... I am able to use guest session fine but i cant get back into my old session...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press ctrl+alt+F1 and input your user name and next input your password. When successfully login, create new user by typing sudo adduser [yourname] ex: sudo adduser creatorb and next complete it field like password and etc. Finally reboot and login with new user account on your light-locker.

Comment: Thanks I got into the desktop and all my softwares are installed.  However I don't think this user is administered anymore. Any advice on switching admin and deleting the corrupt user? Also will changing to admit replace some missing items on my settings window?

Comment: sure you can do that, you can delete user by typing sudo userdel [userName] ex: sudo userdel creatorb and next finish up by deleting your user’s home directory with type sudo rm -rf /home/creatorb (change creatorb to your username). When you want using a user with root privileges you can change new user privilleges on /etc/sudoers edit it by vim/nano or your text editor, ex: i have edited by nano, so type nano /etc/sudoers and set user privilege specification like this [link](http://s25.postimg.org/imyz89i5b/sudoers_creatorb.png)